# Facebook share Og:image error, when image is only less than 200kb

Tags: facebook

Facebook debugger
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fepaper.sinchew.my%2Fsinchewepaper%2Fmobimax%2Freader%2Fmagazine%2Fasd.php

I kept getting this message 
Provided og:image...image link ... could not be downloaded because it exceeded the maximum allowed sized of 8Mb or your server was too slow to respond.

The image is only around 200KB.

Why does this happen? Pls Help!

Comment: have the same issue suddenly, but when I debug the same url again it works.. =/

Comment: Just got this as well. Don't know why.

Comment: Turned out there is a single quote ' after the .JPG in my case. lol
Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but it was solved. In my case, `.access` file concerned it. If you set a `.access` file on your images directory and restrict accesses from others than `home` directory, you may need to change your settings or environment.

Answer (score 0):

+1 for Alexandre T's answer

For me, this problem had to do with my .htaccess file in the root directory of my website.

There was a section enabling hotlink protection, in other words blocking anyone except referrers I specified from accessing my website's image files. Facebook wasn't in that list of allowed referrers, so that's why my images weren't showing up no matter how many times I re-scraped, or whether or not I had specified og:image:height and og:image:width.

The rules that blocked hotlinking may get added to your .htaccess file without you ever actually manually editing it--some servers like BlueHost have a one-click way to enable hotlink protection in your site's cPanel settings.

To fix this, I did two things. I'm pretty sure that the second action does not work on its own and it's probably unnecessary, but I included it b/c you may want to add search engines to your allowed referrers like I did. Here goes:

1) I chose to allow direct requests (which from what I understand is not the same thing as allowing hotlinking, in other words it still provides some hotlink protection)

2) I added a rule that allows facebook.com and fbcdn.net to the list of allowed referrers (along with google, yahoo, bing for good measure)

You can accomplish both of these steps either by using the cPanel Hotlink Protectio module which is a more "user-friendly" interface, or you can edit your .htaccess file directly in file manager or via FTP (and as always, you should back up you .htaccess before you make any changes to it! one mistake and your website won't work at all, but with a backup it only takes a second to replace it with the most recent working version).

[hotlink-protection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urvOf.png)
(screen shot of the hotlink protection module in cPanel, BlueHost)

[configure-hotlink-protection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hApte.png)
(screen shot of hotlink protection settings)

To do step 1 in cPanel, go to hotlink protection, check the box next to "Allow direct requests." Then to do step 2 in cPanel, also add this line into the List of URLS to which you wish to allow access:

```html
($|(http|https):\/\/.*(google\.com|yahoo\.com|bing\.com|facebook\.com|fbcdn\.net))
```

Then save or submit.

To do it by editing your site's .htaccess, once you've created a backup, find the area of the file related to hotlink blocking - for me it was at the end of my .htaccess, not sure where it will be for you.

If you're not sure what to look for, you can search for jpg in the file, because the rewrite rule will include the file extensions being targeted (like png, jpg, jpeg, etc)

This is what the whole hotlink blocking section looked like for me:

```html
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://yoursitename.com/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://yoursitename.com$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://dns.yoursitename.com/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://dns.yoursitename.com$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.dns.yoursitename.com/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.dns.yoursitename.com$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.yoursitename.com/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.yoursitename.com$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://dns.yoursitename.com/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://dns.yoursitename.com$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://yoursitename.com/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://yoursitename.com$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://www.dns.yoursitename.com/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://www.dns.yoursitename.com$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://www.yoursitename.com/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://www.yoursitename.com$      [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp)$ - [F,NC]
```

I'm sure there's a way to concentate all those rules but I personally don't know what it is and I like to keep my tampering in .htaccess to a minimum because I'm not fully comfortable with the syntax.

To do step 1, at the top of this section you can add this line to allow direct requests, which is the same thing as checking the box in cPanel to "Allow direct requests":

```html
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
```

Then to do step 2 and add Facebook, fbcdn (Facebook's CDN or content delivery network), as well as the major search engines, as allowed referrers (notice that this syntax is more streamlined and it includes the https://, http://, www, and non-www versions of the sites):

```html
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^($|(http|https):\/\/.*(fbcdn\.net|facebook\.com|google\.com|yahoo\.com|bing\.com)) [NC]
```